# ModelState.IsValid - but not on the bound model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I can use ModelState.IsValid to a bound model in a controller - and it will return errors according to DataAnnotations - and I can manually add model errors too:

```
public ActionResult Index(string querystr)
{
    // Take querystr, perform actions, hydrate new model

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //Happy path - Log result

        return RedirectToAction("blah");
    }

    // Errors present - Get errors & add to log

    return RedirectToAction("blah");
}
```

However - I need a controller that has a querystring passed into it - then I need to perform some tasks and manually hydrate a new model.

This model obviously isn't bound to the controller - is it still possible to use Model Validation / ModelState.IsValid{} & return DataAnnotation errors?

There will be no user input or binding - these results (and or errors) will just be logged in a database.

If this is possible, how?

I can't find anything online about doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: i think it is possible using Fluent Validation: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

Comment: Yeah that's another option - though currently I'm heavily invested in DataAnnotations

Comment: You can use the [TryUpdateModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel(v=vs.118).aspx) method

Comment: Thanks - how though?! That appears to also be connected to the model bound to the view / controller - not a separate one?!